# Navigation Controller Turns Black on PopViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I have an app in which I have a navigation controller, a root view, and one view that the root pushes to via segue. I'm not doing anything advanced and I am not calling the segue multiple times, but when I pop the second view controller for the second time, the screen goes black and I have to force quit the app. To summarize, when I open the app, I press a button which pushes to the second view, I pop that back to the root view which works fine, but when I do that again the whole screen turns black. Has anyone experienced this before or know how I can fix it?

Thanks for any help.

This is the code that I use to show the controller

```
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showSecondView" sender:self];
```

And this is to close the second view

```
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: It seems that you are poping all the view controllers from the stack and there is no view controller to display. Some code will help finding the issue.

Comment: I added the code. It's very basic and I have used it plenty of times before so I didn't think it was necessary. I have tried commenting those out so I know I am not calling it multiple times.

Comment: So you are doing one push and one pop ? And after that you have the black screen ? Or you are doing a push, pop, push, pop and then you have the black screen ?

Comment: Do you get any errors printed out in the console, like "unbalanced calls to..." ?

Comment: Nope, and I just logged the root view and you are correct that viewWillAppear never gets called the second time.

Comment: To go from the second view controller back to the root view controller, are you tapping the back button in the navigation bar, or are you using something else to determine when to go back to the root view controller?  If you are using the back button, then the popViewController method call is unnecessary.

Comment: Did you connect the segue from the button, or directly from the view controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I was actually performing the segue twice only on the second time though. The problem was that using a NSNotificationCenter notification in a subview of the root view to tell the root view to segue, but not unregistering the observer such that when the root view returned I subscribed to the notification again. That meant that the segue ended up being called twice on the second time because the notification was received twice.